# P-adic expansion of rational

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I want to find the 7adic expansion of 1/4. 
I found that this is …1515152, by using the algorithm of finding 1/4 = k + 7q for each digit. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct. You can easily check this yourself by multiplying your result by 4.

Comment: Alternatively, you can identify the repeating part as $150/(1-100)$ in $7$-ary, that is, $84/(1-49)=-7/4$ in decimal, which you add to the nonrepeating part, namely $2$, to get the right value.